# match exact parts of a string using MATLAB regexp

Tags: regex, matlab

This is the sample string "How to Do FFT in MATLAB YouTube MATLAB 4 minutes, 42 seconds Apr 28, 2022". How do I use a MATLAB regexp to find the part of the string that has xx minutes, yy seconds and extract the string before that?

so far i have tried regexp(string,'[1234567890]','start') and it works qwell until the matlab function name has a number in it. so i want to exact match the minutes, seconds part and extract the string before that

Comment: i now created words = "seconds", idx = regexp(str,words), words.extractBefore(idx-16) (assuming worst case video is also xx minutes long) and that works better for me. still would like to match the xx minutes, yy seconds and if possible zz hours, yy minutes, xx seconds

Comment: This is very hard to provide a complete answer to without a better example set of inputs and your precise expected output for each, including elaboration on the edge cases you've eluded to. Please [edit] your question to expand on the examples

Answer (score 0):

If this run:

```
str = "How to Do FFT in MATLAB YouTube MATLAB 4 minutes, 42 seconds Apr 28, 2022";

result_cell = regexp( ...
    str, ...
    '(\w*) [0-9]* minutes, [0-9]* sec', ...
    'tokens')
out = result_cell{1}{1};
```

This is the result

```
out =
    'MATLAB'
```

Regular expressions are a whole art in themselves. Some features I used above are:

- `\w` matches any "word character
- `*` matches zero or more of the preceding character or group
- `( )` both groups operations (like parentheses usually do) AND triggers the "token" concept, sort of defining the output.
- `[ ]` defines a grouped item